# Discord.py Splitting Emojis from Channel Names

Tags: python, discord.py

Trying to create a list of channels in a category then split the channel name and emojis. Then send an embed from it.

The problem with this is that sometimes the realm name is like #realm-name-emoji:

I use the `-` to split names but in this case I can't do that so is there a way to check if the emoji is an actual emoji? Then using that same emoji, add a reaction to the embed the bot sent.

I marked the issues with a comment here. Is there a better alternative to split the emojis and realm names?

So far I have this:

```py
@commands.command()
    async def checkin(self, ctx):
      if ctx.guild.id != "guild id":
        return
      else:
        category = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.categories, id="my ID here")
        checkinem = discord.Embed(title='Realms Channels')
        
        for channel in category.channels:
          realm, emoji = channel.name.split('-') #issue here
          checkinem.add_field(name=realm, value=emoji, inline=False)
        checkinmsg = await ctx.send(embed=checkinem)

        for channel in category.channels: 
          realm, emoji = channel.name.split('-') #issue here
          await checkinmsg.add_reaction(emoji=emoji)
```

Any help would be great! Thank you!

Comment: you can try with `unicodedata.lookup(str)` but for some emojis like `:white_check_mark:` won't work

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your question, you have two possible channel name :

- #realm-emoji
- #realm-name-emoji

In both cases, the realm is the first element and the emoji is the last element, so, you can check the splitted channel name length :

```py
channel = channel.split('-')
if len(channel) == 2: # #real-emoji
    realm, emoji = channel
else: # #realm-name-emoji  
    realm, emoji = channel[0], channel[-1]
```